# How do you load an image with a react-p5 project?

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I’ve been working on a project to practise using react-p5. I’ve been trying to display an image (which is local — it’s stored in a folder called 'data' inside my project folder) on the canvas, but I’ve been running into problems where the image doesn’t seem to be loading correctly. If I try to place the image on the canvas using p5.image(), I get errors about trying to access properties of an undefined object.

I’ve tried importing the image into my sketch, then loading it using p5’s preload function. I’ve also tried using a callback with p5's loadImage() in the setup function. Neither of these approaches have worked for me and I can’t find a lot of documentation for image loading with react-p5 out there. Has anyone else had trouble loading an image when using react-p5? If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Here is the code of what I’ve tried so far:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Sketch from "react-p5";
import background from "./data/test.png";

const Sample = (props) => {
    const [p5, setP5] = useState(null);
    let backgroundImage;

    const preload = (p5) => {
        backgroundImage = p5.loadImage(background);
    }

    const setup = (p5, parent) => {
        setP5(p5);
        p5.createCanvas(500, 500).parent(parent);
        p5.textAlign(p5.CENTER, p5.CENTER);
        
        // I've also tried loading the image this way
        // p5.loadImage("./data/test.png", img => {
        //     backgroundImage = img;
        //     p5.redraw();
        // })

        p5.noLoop();
        
    }

    const draw = (p5) => {
            p5.image(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
    }

    return <Sketch preload={preload} setup={setup} draw={draw} />
}
export default Sample;
```

Comment: Perhaps the folder could be the culprit here? If "data" is inside your project folder rather than your "src" folder, you would want to refer to it as "../data/test.png" (with two dots at the beginning, to signify the parent folder).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your image to be somewhere in your public folder and have the relative path be relative to your `index.html` file.

If you move it to be in the exact same folder as your `index.html` file, then you can use this:

```js
p5.loadImage("./test.png", img => {
    p5.image(img, 0, 0);
    p5.redraw();
})
```

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage

Comment: Thanks for your response. I moved the image into my public folder and put the code you suggested in my setup() function. Unfortunately, the image still doesn’t show up and I get an Event object that looks like this: `Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: img, currentTarget: img, eventPhase: 2, …}` Have you seen something like this before?